# Optimizing Oracle query by removing 'exists' and 'not exists'

Tags: sql, oracle

I recently moved a piece of code into production on a oracle database where one of the more experienced developer who reviewed it mentioned I had way too many `exists` and `not exists` statements and that there should be a way to remove them, but it had been too long since he had to use it and didn't remember much on how it worked.  Currently, I'm going back and making the piece of code more maintainable as it is a piece likely to be changed multiple times in future years as business logic/requirements change, and I wanted to go ahead and optimize it while making it more maintainable.

I've tried looking it up, but all I can find is recommendations on replacing `not in` with `not exists` and to not return actual results.

As such, I'm wondering what can be done to optimize out `exists`/`not exists` or if there is a way to write `exists`/`not exists` so that oracle will optimize it internally (likely at a better degree than I can).

For example, how can the following be optimized?

```
UPDATE
    SCOTT.TABLE_N N
SET
    N.VALUE_1 = 'Data!'
WHERE
    N.VALUE_2 = 'Y'
    AND
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            SCOTT.TABLE_Q Q
        WHERE
            N.ID = Q.N_ID
    )
    AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            SCOTT.TABLE_W W
        WHERE
            N.ID = W.N_ID
    )
```

Comment: By any chance, was the "more experienced developer" more experienced with MySQL? (In MySQL a left outer join with a select ... where null generally performs better than a not exists clause, but in Oracle and many other databases a not exists clause generally performs better.)

Comment: To my knowledge, he is PL/SQL only and was referring to Oracle PL/SQL Programming by Steven Feuerstein as the source of where he read about the optimization.  There is a chance he may have just been mis-remembering a different optimization; humans do have a known bug where memories can be partially false.

Comment: Google books always seems to bring up this page in the book you mentioned: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vUbJkdl6vIcC&pg=PA848&dq="Oracle+PL/SQL+Programming"+"Steven+Feuerstein"+"not+exists" - which isn't directly relevant. However, this web page: http://dbpedias.com/wiki/Oracle:Coding_Best_Practices_-_Using_EXISTS/NOT_EXISTS (which appears to have been authored by Mr. Feuerstein) essentially makes much the same points as be here now's answer, below. Finally, `minus` may sometimes outperform a `not exists` - see http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/toad/message/23271?source=1&var=1 .

Comment: A side note, but it seems the plsql tag was edited to be a sql tag.  Should I have used both, or is there a reason this to prefer sql?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your statement seems perfectly fine to me.

In any optimizing task, don't think patterns. Don't think like, "`(not) exists` is bad and slow, `(not) in` is super cool and fast".

Think like, how much work does database do on each step and how can you measure it?

A simple example:

**-- NOT IN:**

```
23:59:41 HR@sandbox> alter system flush buffer_cache;

System altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
23:59:43 HR@sandbox> set autotrace traceonly explain statistics
23:59:49 HR@sandbox> select country_id from countries where country_id not in (select country_id from locations);

11 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1748518851

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                 |     1 |     6 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                |                 |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS ANTI SNA|                 |    11 |    66 |     4  (75)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN     | COUNTRY_C_ID_PK |    25 |    75 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN    | LOC_COUNTRY_IX  |    13 |    39 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | LOCATIONS       |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "LOCATIONS" "LOCATIONS" WHERE
              "COUNTRY_ID" IS NULL))
   4 - access("COUNTRY_ID"="COUNTRY_ID")
   5 - filter("COUNTRY_ID" IS NULL)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         11  consistent gets
          8  physical reads
          0  redo size
        446  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        363  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         11  rows processed
```

**-- NOT EXISTS**

```
23:59:57 HR@sandbox> alter system flush buffer_cache;

System altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.17
00:00:02 HR@sandbox> select country_id from countries c where not exists (select 1 from locations l where l.country_id = c.country_id );

11 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.30

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 840074837

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                 |    11 |    66 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS ANTI|                 |    11 |    66 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN | COUNTRY_C_ID_PK |    25 |    75 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| LOC_COUNTRY_IX  |    13 |    39 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("L"."COUNTRY_ID"="C"."COUNTRY_ID")


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          5  consistent gets
          2  physical reads
          0  redo size
        446  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        363  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         11  rows processed
```

NOT IN in this example reads twice as much database blocks and performs more complicated filtering - ask yourself, why would you chose it over NOT EXISTS?

Comment: What should I make of the times each take, as it appears `not in` takes 1/15th the time `not exists` takes.  Or am I just misreading the data?

Comment: @Lawtonfogle you mean, my example, 0.02 vs 0.3? that's basically a wall-clock time, it includes time elapsed on displaying output in my  sql*plus window, and it may vary. I just re-ran these queries and it happened to be 0.03 for "not exists" and 0.07 for "not in". if you want accurate timing you should check either sql trace or probably somewhere in v$sql_plan_statistics

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to avoid using EXISTS or NOT EXISTS when that is what you need.  In the example you gave, that is probably exactly what you want to use.

The typical dilemma is whether to use IN/NOT IN, or EXISTS/NOT EXISTS. They are evaluated quite differently, and one may be faster or slower depending on your specific circumstances.

See [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074) for more details than you probably want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is much faster, but here is a way to write it without `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_N T
USING (
  SELECT N.ID, 'Data!' AS NEW_VALUE_1
  FROM SCOTT.TABLE_N N
  INNER JOIN SCOTT.TABLE_Q Q
      ON Q.N_ID = N.ID
  LEFT JOIN SCOTT.TABLE_W W
      ON W.N_ID = N.ID
  WHERE N.VALUE_2 = 'Y'
  AND W.ID IS NULL
) X
ON ( T.ID = X.ID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET T.VALUE_1 = X.NEW_VALUE_1;
```